# .click по двум id

Tags: jquery, javascript

есть код:

```
$('#pollSlider-button').click(function () {
    if ($(this).css("margin-right") == "300px") {            
        $('#mask').remove();            
        $('.pollSlider').animate({
            "margin-right": '-=300',                
        });

        $('#pollSlider-button').animate({
            "margin-right": '-=300'
        });                            
    } else {
        // Add the mask to body            
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
        $('.pollSlider').animate({
            "margin-right": '+=300', 
            "width": '=300'               
        });
        $('#pollSlider-button').animate({
            "margin-right": '+=300',
            "width": '=300'
        });
    }

});
```

так вот, при клике на #pollSlider-button происходит вся работа, но мне нужно, что бы и при клике на #pollSlider-button и при #mask происходило действие. Подскажите как правильно.

Comment: А разве уже запрещено добавлять несколько селекторов?

    $('#pollSlider-button, #pollSlider-button, #mask').click(function(){
   
    });

Конечно логичней для такой группы элементов, задать какой-то один класс и использовать его в качестве селекутора, но это дело ваше.

Comment: добавлял как группу, вот сам #mask 

#mask {
    display: none;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;    
}

кликаю по нем, ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не?

http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/UT4wJ/1/

Comment: писал же, не помогло

Comment: @foozzi, в таких случаях, выкладывайте код на [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/). Но вы человек на форуме новый (*всего-то 1 год и четыре месяца*) и об этом, возможно, еще не знали.

Comment: @foozzi, а вы вторую строчку меняли, так же как у меня?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/foozzi/UT4wJ/

Comment: используйте `.on()` у вас '#mask' пересоздается...

Comment: Обновил ответ, http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/UT4wJ/1/ (первый раз невнимательно посмотрел код)